# Rubber fails during create_staging Bundler::GemfileNotFound ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-4, rubber

This is my first time deploying an app to an ec2 instance. It seems most of the process worked but eventually the deploy failed with the following error:

```
failed: "/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mnt/depot-production/releases/20130312030226 && bundle install --gemfile /mnt/depot-production/releases/20130312030226/Gemfile --path /mnt/depot-production/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test staging'" on production.foo.com
```

I logged into my server and went to the directory and tried to execute the command. The following error was displayed:

```
Bundler::GemfileNotFound
```

When I list the contents of the directory, it shows a gemfile. Just could use some help in determining why it is not found and how to fix it.

I'm also not exactly sure how to proceed? I would like to simply fix the error and continue on with the instance that was created but not sure what steps all need to be executed.

Comment: Perhaps this link might help: http://blog.willj.net/2011/08/02/fixing-the-gemfile-not-found-bundlergemfilenotfound-error/

Comment: I also saw this article but I'm not using Unicorn so I'm not sure how to change that environment variable. Is there somewhere I can update this variable and then try rerunning the command? Needless to say I'm quite inexperienced with rails development.. just trying to learn.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I may have figured it out. The gemfile is lowercase in the production folder (ie gemfile not Gemfile) ... but it seems bundler was expecting uppercased Gemfile. After copying:

    cp gemfile Gemfile

I can run bundle install. Which seems to be working now.